# creating a multitenant SPA backed by restful web services

Tags: javascript, java, deployment, architecture, multi-tenant

I am trying to create a multi tenant SPA (Single Page App) using HTML5/Javascript. This app will invoke restful webservices for data updates. Below is in illustration to the architecture:  [image]

These are my challenges:

- Identity : How will a service know that a request coming from a client side JS corresponds to a particular schema in the database? May be I can send an "APPID" token? But, this can be spoofed easily by the end user?
- Connection Pooling : If tomcat pool is relied upon for connection pooling, how do I ensure that connections created using "app1" credentials, which has access to APP1 schema are returned to the webservice when it handles requests from App1 JS? I can possibly, just create one database account which has access to all schemas, but this can probably become a compliance issue.

Should I just deploy multiple copies of the webservices? Say, app1 JS queries services.app1.com and app2 JS queries services.app2.com? This would probably solve the above two issues, but I don't think it is a multi tenant solution anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally accomplished by a token that is authenticated.  This is normally handled by a standard session cookie (implemented by whatever application server you are using), or something less stateful (like an [OAuth bearer token](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html)) that gets validated on each call.  This is ultimately the same solution, one using a cookie (which is implemented via a HTTP header), the other is using an Auth http header.  Regardless, what basically happens is that each user is issued a magic string, which is authenticated on each call as belonging to a particular set of credentials.

It is fairly similar to your "APPID" in theory, the difference is that the tokens are opaque, and very likely unguessable do to their length and complexity (before the heat-death of the universe), and thus are effectively secure.  The difference is that you hold the binding between the token and which "APPID" on the server side, not on the client side.

Comment: Thanks Rob, for your answer. Is there any library that implements or makes it easy to make use of Oauth bearer tokens for javascript/java combination?

Comment: OAuth is pretty straightforward if you want to respect someone else's authentication (it's how the login via facebook or google type things work):  http://nat.sakimura.org/2014/12/10/making-a-javascript-openid-connect-client  is an example.  Creating your own provider is a bit more in-depth... you probably want to use a package like OpenAM http://openam.forgerock.org/.  All this being said, unless you are using multiple servers, I'd really start with a plain old session unless you really need the complexity.